# bash extension modules on python

Tags: python, bash

I know that it is possible to write bash extension modules (loadable builtins) on C or lua (see luabash), but is it possible on Python/Cython? Is there any projects that make steps in this direction?

Comment: I came across [plumbum](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumbum) but don't know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The way you would probably do this is start out with a C library which includes the appropriate exported functions, then within the exported function load and run the python interpreter, run your python code, then tear down the python interpreter.

You can see how to load the python interpreter into a C program/library here:

- http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html
- http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497

If you do this a lot, then it may be simpler to write a single generic handler when you can use with multiple different python scripts.

Comment: So you mean that I need to write C-wrapper first and then just use python in this wrapper? Yes, that's clear, but I look for some projects that have already done something in the direction

Comment: The "embedding" doc page and the linuxjournal article both have fairly extensive examples.

Comment: I know all these things but it is not enough. I want something like luabash but for python

Comment: @IgorChubin luabash is very simple -- a single C file. And the loaded python interpreter is very similar to the lua interpreter. Using the documentation I linked, you could very easily translate luabash.c to use the python interpreter instead of lua.

Answer (score 0):

I used Bash examples and the linked resources @tylerl mentioned to make [bashpy](https://github.com/nflx/bashpy). It's a proof of concept and currently lacks support for both passing variables and calling functions. So not very useful yet, but maybe it can help someone ending up here.